# Microsoft sql server: Pivot rows together with concatenate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a select query that outputs as follows:

```
pid-------Name------------------response
147------Factory Influenced-----Fish Paste
147------Factory Influenced-----Contract Packer
147------Factory Influenced-----Cereals
147------Factory Influenced-----Biscuits
154------Factory Influenced-----Werda
154------Factory Influenced-----Worcester
158------Factory Influenced-----Moirs
158------Factory Influenced-----Oats
158------Factory Influenced-----Noogy
157------Factory Influenced-----Safari Nuts
158------Factory Influenced-----Savoury Foods
```

What I would like to do is make 'Factory Influenced' a column and the 'response' the fields. However I would like to concatenate these values as follows:

```
pid-----Factory Influenced          
147-----Fish Paste, Contract Packer, Cereals, Biscuits          
154-----Werda, Worcester            
158-----Moirs, Oats, Noogy, Safari Nuts, Savoury Foods
```

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This process of concatenating multiple rows into a single column is not PIVOT, a PIVOT is when you convert rows of data into columns.  Since you want to create a comma-separated list of values the code is different.

You can use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to create the list:

```
select t1.pid,
  t1.name, 
  STUFF(
         (SELECT ', ' + t2.response
          FROM yourtable t2
          where t1.pid = t2.pid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS response
from yourtable t1
group by t1.pid, t1.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bd97/1).

Or you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select DISTINCT t1.pid,
  t1.name, 
  response = left(t2.response, len(t2.response)-1) 
from yourtable t1
cross apply
(
  select t2.response + ', '
  from yourtable t2
  where t1.pid = t2.pid
  FOR XML PATH('')
) t2 (response);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1bd97/4). Both versions will give a result of:

```
| PID |               NAME |                                       RESPONSE |
|-----|--------------------|------------------------------------------------|
| 147 | Factory Influenced | Fish Paste, Contract Packer, Cereals, Biscuits |
| 154 | Factory Influenced |                               Werda, Worcester |
| 157 | Factory Influenced |                                    Safari Nuts |
| 158 | Factory Influenced |              Moirs, Oats, Noogy, Savoury Foods |
```

Comment: thanks @bluefeet. managed to alter this to return exactly what i wanted as above. appreciate it.